# Get InputStream of bundle already installed in OSGi runtime?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, equinox

I am trying to create a backup file of a bundle that is installed in the runtime, so that I can uninstall it and then possibly reinstall from the backup if I want.  Does anybody know how to get a handle on the location of the bundle file that is already installed in the runtime?  I would like to do this in a way that will work regardless of OSGi container (specifically, I want it to work in Equinox and Felix).  Ideally this would be information gained from the `Bundle` object (or from information from an object acquired from the `Bundle` object).

Edit:  In a nutshell, I am getting every bundle installed (`bundleContext.getBundles`) and from that attempting to determine file paths of the bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. The OSGi spec does not provide any way to get the input stream for an installed bundle. This is mostly because the OSGi does not require that bundles come in the form of a JAR nor that they be stored in any archive format. For example, an OSGi framework could store the entries of a bundle in a database and then look up requested classes and resources from that database. So you see there is no guarantee the bundles exist in JAR form after installation.

Comment: I don't like this answer, but it seems to be the unfortunate truth.

Answer (score 0):

Use bundle.getLocation(). It will return the location the bundle was installed from (if available). There is no guarantee that you can load the bundle jar from there but depending on how you originally installed the bundle this works.

Comment: It looks like this would work with equinox (at least when running my container via Eclipse, I'm not sure if the behavior would be the same when running it from the tycho-surefire plugin, for example), but this doesn't work for Felix, as Felix installs the bundle in a different location.

Comment: Of course the bundles might originate from different locations but you can still backup them from the given location.